# Acessing session attribute from jsp page using logic tag

Tags: jsp, struts

I want to access the role session attribute (which i have set during authentication) from a jsp page and check whteher its value is equal to "admin" or "user". How do i do this using the logic tag.

Comment: Do you mean you have added an attribute to the session? What's the attribute called?

Comment: the attribute is called role, it has to be checked with the string 'admin'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your session attribute is called "role":

```
<logic:equal name="role" value="admin" scope="session">
    etc
</logic:equal>
```

You can omit the scope attribute if you like as without it the tag will look in any scope (page, request, session)

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a favor, and forget about the logic tags. Use the JSTL and the JSP EL instead:

```
<c:if test="${role == 'admin' or role == 'user'}">
    ...
</c:if>
```

[Struts documentation](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/dev_logic.html) itself discourages the use of logic tags, and promotes the use of the JSTL:

> Note: - Many of the features in this taglib are also available in the
>   JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library (JSTL). The Apache Struts group
>   encourages the use of the standard tags over the Struts specific tags
>   when possible.

Comment: this code gives the following error  JSPG0124E: Custom tag attribute test cannot be runtime expression. value: "[${role == 'admin'}]"

Comment: Then you have a problem with your JSTL install. Of course the test attribute of c:if can be an EL expression.